# Determining the circumdiameter of a triangle, given the distance from a vertex to the orthocenter and the length of the opposite side

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles, recreational-mathematics

**Problem I'm trying to solve:**

> Given triangle $ABC$ inscribed in a circle a shown. The altitudes of the triangle meet at point $P$. $AP=21\text{cm}$ and $BC=20\text{cm}$. What is the diameter of the circle?
>
> [image]

**My Attempt**

Let the point where the altitude of $AB$ meets $AB$ be $Q$,the point where the altitude of $AC$ meets $AC$ be $R$ and the point where the altitude of $BC$ meets $BC$ be $S$. Then let $PQ$ be $21x$. From the similarity of $\triangle APQ$ and $\triangle BCQ$, $BQ=20x$ and by the pythagorean theorem $BP=29x$. It's relatively easy to see that $\triangle AQP \sim \triangle ABS \sim \triangle PCS \sim \triangle BCQ$ and pretty much the same for most other triangles that can be found in the circle however I'm lost as to where to go from there since everything else just seems to give lengths of triangle sides in terms of $x$.

I've also tried drawing radii and diameters through the vertices of the triangle in order to determine some possible relation between the angles, sides and the circle's radius but this doesn't seem to get anywhere either.

My original idea was to determine the area of triangle and the sides of the triangle from which the radius readily follows but I just seem to have too little information to move forward with anything? I don't think there's a way to apply Ptolemy's theorem or any other theorem here so I just simply don't know how to move forward.

Comment: Not a proof: A guess would be to consider triangles with $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$, then the orthocenter $P=B$, then the diameter $AC = \sqrt{20^2+21^2} = 29\text{ cm}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Similar to the question attempt,) Consider the similar triangles $\triangle AQP\sim \triangle CQB$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{AQ}{QC} &= \frac{21}{20}\\
&= \cot\angle QAC
\end{align*}$$

Then what follows is essentially the same as what the sine law describes, applying on $\triangle ABC$:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Circumdiameter} &= \frac{BC}{\sin\angle QAC}\\
&= {20}\sqrt{1+\cot^2\angle QAC}\\
&= 29\text{ cm}
\end{align*}$$

---

Construct $A'$ on the same side of $BC$ as $A$, where $A'B \perp BC$ and $A'B = 21\text{ cm}$. (Whether $A'$ is on the same circumcircle is to be proven.)

[image: Diagram with A' added]

So these right-angled triangles are similar: $\triangle A'BC \sim \triangle AQC$ (SAS).

The corresponding angles $\angle BA'C = \angle QAC = \angle BAC$ (also equal to $\cot^{-1}\frac{21}{20}$), so $A,A',B,C$ are concyclic.

$A'B \perp BC$ by construction, and the diameter of their circumcircle is

$$A'C = \sqrt{20^2+21^2} = 29\text{ cm}$$

Comment: But how do you know that the line segment $A’B$ is perpendicular to  BC if and only if its length is 21cm (since you can uniquely define the end point of $A’B$ on the circle purely based on its length or its angle with $BC$)? P.S. what did you use to make the diagram?

Comment: You start with "*Construct $A'$ on the same side of $BC$ as $A$, where $A'B \perp BC$ and $A'B = 21\text{ cm}$.*". How do you know that $A'$ is located on the circle?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean

Comment: @d0uble_a_b4ttery $A'$ was not constructed "on the circle", but by $A'B \perp BC$ and $A'B = 21\text{ cm}$. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Dominique $A'$ was not constructed "on the circle", but by $A'B \perp BC$ and $A'B = 21\text{ cm}$. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: ... later you state that $A$, $A'$, $B$ and $C$ are concyclic. Is that so? How do you know that?

Comment: @Dominique ... because $\angle BA'C = \angle BAC$.

Comment: K I understand now! I've upvoted and accepted your answer.